DBT calling macro as a post_hook where the macro uses variable from the table
I have a model called stg_dates which compiles a list of dates and reference_id that a call procedure (in snowflake) runs through to preform some calculations.
I have this set-up as:
run_dates.sql
{{ config(materialized='ephemeral') }}
{% set _ = ref('stg_dates') %}
{% do iq_model_run_liability_benchmark() %}

and have defined the macro as:
{% macro iq_model_run_liability_benchmark() %}
    {{ log("Running model", info=True) }}
    {% set table_ref = ref('stg_dates') %}
    {% set query %}
        SELECT ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE
        FROM {{ table_ref }}
    {% endset %}
    {% set results = run_query(query) %}

    {% for row in results.rows %}
        {{ log("Running liability benchmark for EFFECTIVE_DATE: " ~ row["EFFECTIVE_DATE"] ~ ", LBP_ID: " ~ row["LBP_ID"], info=True) }}
        {% set sql_statement %}
            CALL TEST_DB.MODEL_SCHEMA.RUN_TASK (True,'{{ row["EFFECTIVE_DATE"] }}','{{ row["ID"] }}');
        {% endset %}

        {% do run_query(sql_statement) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

however i get the error none as table when i try to run run_dates.sql model.
I believe the issue is to do with the order the models are complied but i can't seem to get it to run without this error. or how to fix the order of model creation. I could also be on the wrong  lines here!
We need to run this macro in order so can't run it outside as a run-operation command (which does work)

There are a few things going on when I read this, but since you say the (first) error is none as table perhaps you can put ref('stg_dates') inside the select statement instead of using table_ref as a variable. The jinja replacement inside of macros is a complication.
